# Retrofit2 & JSON response array with multiple possible values

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I haven't written anything here for a long time, but now I really need advice )

I'm using Retrofit2 as api client. Server API has one endpoint, for example `/api/stats` which receive JSON body **request** and return JSON **response** as:

```
data class StatsResult<T>(
    @SerializedName("code")         val code: Int,
    @SerializedName("message")      val msg: String?,
    @SerializedName("request_id")   val requestId: String?,
    @SerializedName("data")         val data: T?
)
```

If some error, `data` is null.
Otherwise `data` is an array that can contain different type of data depending on the type of **request**.

For example:

Request1:

```
{
   "type": "type1",
   "params": {
   }
}

Response:
{
    "code": 0,
    "request_id": "...",
    "data": [
        {
            "key1": "value1",
            "key2": "value2"
        },
        {
            "key1": "value3",
            "key2": "value4"
        }
    ]
}
```

Request2:

```
{
   "type": "type2",
   "params": {
   }
}

Response:
{
    "code": 0,
    "request_id": "...",
    "data": [
        {
            "key3": "value1",
            "key4": "value2"
        },
        {
            "key3": "value3",
            "key4": "value4"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is my implementation in short:

```
interface StatsApi {
    @POST("/api/stats")
    suspend fun getStats(@Body request: StatsRequest): ApiResponse<StatsData>
}

sealed class ApiResponse<out T: Any> {
    data class Success<T: Any>(val body: T): ApiResponse<T>()
    object Unauthorized : ApiResponse<Nothing>()
    object Forbidden: ApiResponse<Nothing>()
    object NetworkError: ApiResponse<Nothing>()
    data class Error(val msg: String? = null): ApiResponse<Nothing>()
    data class Exception(val t: Throwable): ApiResponse<Nothing>()
}

typealias StatsData = StatsResult<List<BaseStatsDto>>

open class BaseStatsDto()

class Type1StatsDto: BaseStatsDto() {
    @SerializedName("key1") var key1: String? = null
    @SerializedName("key2") var key2: String? = null
}

class Type2StatsDto: BaseStatsDto() {
    @SerializedName("key3") var key3: String? = null
    @SerializedName("key4") var key4: String? = null
}
```

So I tried to workaround this with open/abstract class `BaseStatsDto` and than cast it to final class. But this solution didn't work.

For response handling I'm using `CallAdapter.Factory()` with custom `Call<>`:

```
open class ApiResponseCall<T : Any>( 
    private val delegate: Call<T>
) : Call<ApiResponse<T>> {

override fun enqueue(callback: Callback<ApiResponse<T>>) {
    return delegate.enqueue(object : Callback<T> {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<T>, t: Throwable) {
            val rsp = when (t) {
                is IOException -> ApiResponse.NetworkError
                else -> ApiResponse.Exception(t)
            }
            callback.onResponse(this@ApiResponseCall, Response.success(rsp))
        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<T>, response: Response<T>) {
            val rsp: ApiResponse<T>
            rsp = if (response.isSuccessful) {
                val body = response.body()
                ApiResponse.Success(body as T)
            } else {
                val code = response.code()
                val error = response.errorBody()
                when (code) {
                    401 -> ApiResponse.Unauthorized
                    403 -> ApiResponse.Forbidden
                    in 400..499 -> ApiResponse.Error("Client error")
                    in 500..599 -> ApiResponse.Error("Server error")
                    else -> ApiResponse.Exception(Exception("Unknown error"))
                }
            }
            callback.onResponse(this@ApiResponseCall, Response.success(rsp))
        }
    })
}
...
}
```

**I see another solution - to have separate interface functions with separate response types. And it working fine:**

```
@POST("/api/stats")
suspend fun getType1Stats(@Body request: StatsRequest): ApiResponse<StatsResult<List<Type1StatsDto>>>

@POST("/api/stats")
suspend fun getType2Stats(@Body request: StatsRequest): ApiResponse<StatsResult<List<Type2StatsDto>>>
```

But if statistic data types count increases it will be very uncomfortable to maintain.

I would like to have one statistic api endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Use http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ Set SourceType: JSON and Annonation style: Gson

Data for request 1

```
class Data1 {
@SerializedName("key1")
@Expose
var key1: String? = null

@SerializedName("key2")
@Expose
var key2: String? = null
}
```

Response of request1

```
class Response1 {
@SerializedName("code")
@Expose
var code: Int? = null

@SerializedName("request_id")
@Expose
var requestId: String? = null

@SerializedName("data")
@Expose
var data: List<Data1>? = null
}
```

Data for request 2

```
 class Data2 {
@SerializedName("key3")
@Expose
var key3: String? = null

@SerializedName("key4")
@Expose
var key4: String? = null
}
```

Response of request 2

```
class Response1 {
@SerializedName("code")
@Expose
var code: Int? = null

@SerializedName("request_id")
@Expose
var requestId: String? = null

@SerializedName("data")
@Expose
var data: List<Data2>? = null
}
```

with

```
@POST("/api/stats")
suspend fun getStats1(@Body request: StatsRequest1): ApiResponse<Response1>
@POST("/api/stats")
suspend fun getStats2(@Body request: StatsRequest2): ApiResponse<Response2>
```

Comment: Thank you for reply! As I wrote at the end of my question this solution is working, but I would like to have one api endpoint for all statistic data